# How can we show $Aut ( \mathbb{Z}_{9})$ is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

We need to show $Aut ( \mathbb{Z}_{9})$ is cyclic.

My attempt : there are 6 elements. So there must be $id$ . Now we could figure that there is exist $g = 2x$, it's obviously not equal $id$. And also we can show that $<2x> = \{4x,6x,8x,id,-2x,-4x \}$. Now is it true that $2x$ is generating element ?

Comment: If you know a group  is of order 6, it suffices to show it is abelian to show it is cyclic.

Comment: $2$ is a generator, that's enough.

Comment: You can use \langle and \rangle for $\langle$ and $\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed there are $6$ elements, as the automorphisms are uniquely determined by the action on the generator $1$. Let $g$ ge an automorphism given by $g(1) = 2$. Then we have that $g(2) = 4, g(4) = 8, g(5) = 1, g(7) = 5, g(8) = 7$

Then we have $g^6(1) = g^5(2) = g^4(4) = g^3(8) = g^2(7) = g(5) = 1$

This is enough to conclude that $g$ has order of $6$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_9})$ and so it's cyclic.